# Inter-filter bit width

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, bitdepth

I'm designing a $2$-stage filter and was simulating the effect of quantization to a certain number of bits at the filter output.  The result I got was far from expected - and would appreciate any intuition from the experts here.

The high-level idea is:

1. Filter input data is $N$ bits.
2. $\rm Stage_1$ is a half-band interpolation by $2$.
3. Internally the filter accuracy is maintained (to approx $30$ bits), but the output is rounded to $M$ bits.
4. The $2^{\textrm{nd}}$ stage takes the $M$ bits in, filters it at full accuracy (again a half-band interpolation by $2$ filter, with full precision internally)
5. The output of the filter is rounded to $P$ bits.

Initially I set $N=M=P$ to be $16$-bits. The filters themselves have a stop-band attenuation of $\approx90\textrm{ dB}$. What surprised me was $16$-bits between filters was not enough - at least in terms of the frequency response.

So if I do not quantize the inter-filter values I of course get ideal behaviour and the overall frequency response (measured via an FFT of an impulse response) is the combination of each individual frequency response - and my stop-band attenuation is $\approx90\textrm{ dB}$. Of course the input bit-width does not matter here.

However, if I quantize to $16$-bits between stages, with rounding, I would have thought this more than sufficient to preserve the filter frequency response accuracy - but I was wrong - the stop-band attenuation dropped to $\approx84\textrm{ dB}$ in places. It required $18$-bits inter-filter bit-width in order to maintain performance.

So the question is - is there a rule of thumb for how many bits to preserve. Why is $16$-bits not enough for $\approx90\textrm{ dB}$ attenuation?

Comment: Looking at the question I cannot see if it's a floating point or fixed point or an integer implementation. I think it matters in defining the dynamic range...

Comment: This is a fixed-point implementation. I used floating point only to check the delta between the ideal case and the fixed-point case.

Comment: ok. I suspect if it's $20 \log_{10}(2^{15}) = 90.30$, very roughly, is the reason why you'll have difficulty in representing a 90 dB dynamic range under 16-Bit uniform quantization. For nonuniform quantization (FPU) things can change.

Comment: Does the output from the first stage look alright after re-quantizing to 16-bit? It could be a quantization artifact, so depending on how you measure, it could include non-linear effects. Have you tried dithering when re-quantizing?

Comment: In general as a rule of thumb, to maintain a 90 dB signal path SNR, the number of bits in the signal path must be 15 bits ((90-1.76)/6 if a sine wave, more if the peak-avg ratio in your signal is higher), so 16 bits sounds right. The coefficients should be 2 bits larger to ensure the filter rejection will exceed the 90dB (so 18 bits), and then all taps are accumulated with extended precision (at least $log_2(K)$ for a K-tap FIR. The final accumulated result can be scaled back to 16 bits, and you should have no problem with achieving your rejection and SNR requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A source of dynamic range issues can be quantization leading to noise increase in your summation if in the datapath or errors in the frequency response if the coefficients themselves have too much rounding error. Quantization noise for an $K$-tap FIR filter can increase as much as $10 \log_{10}K$ in dB when you scale the signal at the input of the filter.  This is the reason for extended precision accumulators; good practice is to let the filter grow the signal and then attenuate after the filter.  Also equally important is that your coefficients should be (as a rule-of-thumb) at least $DR/6 + 2$ bits in precision where $DR$ is the stop-band rejection requirement of your filter.

To the extent that each signal at each tap in your filter can be considered uncorrelated (and this holds if the signal is white, however your first filter will provide some correlation between delay taps reducing the total increase in the noise).

See the figures pasted below that compare the three ways to scale the signal.

To explain these figures, this is the case of a filter with a fixed precision datapath, and a case where due to the input level of the signal, the filter would overflow (since the signal within the bandwidth will increase by a factor of $K$ in magnitude). To keep the filter from overflowing, the filter designer can scale the input, or scale the coefficients, or (the right answer) is allow the filter to grow in precision, and then scale the output.  In the first two cases, the noise would be the quantization noise due to the scaling, and grow in magnitude by the $\sqrt{K}$ (stated differently, variance grows as $K$, standard deviation grows by $\sqrt{K}$), in the last case the noise is just the quantization noise due to the scaling (6.02 dB/bit + 1.76dB for a full scale sine wave) without further growth.

(Note $\Delta^2/12$ denotes the variance due to quantization noise, where $\Delta$ is one LSB step size)

[image: FIR scaling the input]

[image: FIR scaling the coefficients]

[image: FIR scaling the output]

Comment: Thanks, yes that is confusing. Let me fix that!

Comment: Yeah not too hard as they are screen captures from old power point slides I have... it is confusing otherwise so glad you pointed that out. Otherwise I hope the explanation is clear enough.

Comment: well, i can't tell if the OP's filters are FIR or IIR.  also i never heard of the "rule-of-thumb" that the coefficients should be 2 bits wider than the signal data path. they're not directly related. the width of the data words has to do with quantization noise (as you are illustrating) but the width of the coefficient words is related to how precisely the placement of the poles and zeros of the filter and how closely the filter matches its target frequency response.  coefficient quantization is particularly a problem for the stopband.

Comment: Hi Robert, I developed that rule of thumb myself for the case of an FIR filter in practice after reviewing what stobband rejection can be achieved for several cases of rounding.  You can also see this by reviewing the formula for the passband response of a filter as a series of spinning phasors each scaled by the filter coefficients, with increasing rate. (For example, the frequency response for a 3 tap FIR is $H(\omega) = c_1+c_2e^{-j\omega}+c_3e^{-j2\omega} $). From this  you may better be able to see the impact of coefficient rounding on the frequency response.

Comment: i just use MATLAB or Octave to plot responses.  but if you have 32-bit data paths (because you want to keep the quantization noise to a minimum), that does not mean you need 34-bit coefficients.  and it goes the other way.  one might be satisfied with 16-bit data paths, but need coefficients that are wider than 18 bits.

Comment: Right agreed you do not need 34 bit coefficients for noise. The coefficient requirement is based strictly on the rejection requirement of the filter. If you need 90 dB rejection, my recommendation (based on my rule of thumb from prior review of MATLAB and Octave plots) is to have a coefficient precision of at least 90/6 + 2 =  17 bits.  If the filter design itself with floating point precision will meet or exceed the 90 dB rejection requirement, 17 bit coefficients will maintain this but 15 bits may not, and 14 bits certainly won't (throughout the stopband).

Comment: what you're saying is true regarding the number of coefficient bits needed for whatever stopband, but it is **still** not related to the width of the signal data.

Comment: @robert bistrow-johnson: Ah I see your issue now, I explained it as 2 bits wider than the data-path instead of 2 bits wider than the rejection requirement. Very good- thanks for the improvement, I fixed that. Hopefully clearer now.

Comment: well, i dunno how to measure rejection ratio in units of bits.  (yes i know bits are dimensionless, like radians.) unless you're equating rejection ratio as the dynamic range (which is dB S/N + dB headroom) and use the 6.02 dB per bit.  the quantization of coefficients affect other features besides the stopband.  it affects the transition bands and the passband as well.  might do the most damage to a sharp transition band.  errors in the passband are less visible on a dB scale. so your extended precision accumulator bits have to be K + coef width + signal width.

Comment: I use "counts" as the dimension in integer steps of the lsb which is a magnitude quantity (so my unit is "counts"). For instance an 8 bit sine wave at full scale has a magnitude of 127 counts (with a standard deviation (SD) of $127/\sqrt{8}$, it's lsb is 1 count and it's quantizaiton noise has an SD of $1/\sqrt{12}$ cnts. So ratios in dB are 20Log10(ratio of counts). (The ratio of the SD is in fact how the ubiquitous equation for ADC SNR is derived: $\textrm{SNR}= 6 \textrm{dB/bit} + 1.76 \textrm{dB}$ . I deal with comm x-ceivers where the datapath is often derived from an SNR/DR requirement.

Comment: i'm pretty familiar with the math regarding uniform quantization and getting consistent definition of bits of resolution (it's really the dynamic range in dB divided by 6.02) when there are "marketing bits" and legit noisy bits in the quantization. the quantization is $$\left\lfloor \frac{u}{\Delta} \right\rfloor$$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the `floor(x)` operator. $\Delta$ is in whatever units $u$ is in. BTW, there are things you can do like dither (and there is a cheap high-pass dither) and noise-shaping that can increase the salient resolution with the same word widths.

Comment: Thanks Robert - I do actually use extended precision accumulators - basically 'internally' in the filter I preserve the full bit-with of all mult/sums - and only at the very output stage do I round/saturate.

Comment: @John McGrath - I am curious if any of this applied, in particular quantization of coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

I have observed an interesting result - which I think highlights perhaps a weakness in using an impulse response through the quantized data-path to measure the overall performance. In all cases tests below my coefficients are the same, and are always quantized. The results are:

1. Using no datapath quantization - I get the overall ideal filter-chain response when doing an fft of the impulse response.
2. As in my initial post - when I quantized the data-path to 16-bits at the output of each filter stage, and re-doing the impulse response, the fft of this showed a degraded result - which led to the original post
3. I ran another test - this time using a sweep of individual coherent sine waves and doing an FFT of the filtered result. Running this through the same quantized data-path as in 2) shows the true frequency response (albeit in a non-mathematical way) - and I was surprised to see that the stop-band profile matched the ideal result and not the degraded stop-band that produced via 2)

So the good news is it appears 16-bit between filter stages is good enough to ensure the performance I need. The interesting thing appears to be the fact that the impulse response test does not correctly show this.

I'd be interested to hear if others have seen something like this, and could suggest an alternative method to measure the true frequency response of a quantized filter chain.

Comment: You wrote that you are finding the frequency response by doing an FFT- The continuous frequency response for a digital FIR is determined from the DTFT, $H(\omega)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}c_ne^{jn\omega}$ as opposed to the DFT (which the FFT implements). The DTFT is a continuous function in frequency while the FFT is discrete. The two will be identical at the FFT samples points for the FFT that is the same length as your filter, but you are likely interpolating by some method to get the additional samples which would cause response errors if not done as a DTFT.

Comment: To see a response that matches your tone testing, either use the freqz command in Matlab/Octave (freqz([coeff]), or zero pad your FIR filter coefficients prior to taking the FFT.  Zero padding a sequence prior to taking the FFT will properly interpolate samples in the frequency domain for creating samples of the continuous frequency response, and these interpolated samples will be exactly on the DTFT.  (In Matlab/Octave the fft includes a zero padding option: fft(coeff,M) for example will pad out your sequence to M samples total and this should accurately give you your frequency response.

Comment: Quantization is a non-linear operation, so the transfer-function in terms of frequency response is not (fully) defined. The transfer will depend on input, so you will get inconsistent results. Dithering mostly solve these inconsistencies for quantization or re-quantizaton.

Comment: The frequency response due to quantization effects of the coefficients themselves is precisely defined. It is just a rounding of numbers and the resulting response is exact. @Arnfinn the effect you are describing is quantization of the datapath but that does not apply to rounding of the coefficients (to make it clear consider a system with a 32 bit datapath but the coefficients are rounded to 16 bits (not the output of the multiplier, only the coefficients themselves).

Comment: @Dan Boschen: I thought he did re-quantize between filters, potentially introducing some distortion.. maybe I misunderstood, sorry about that

Comment: @Arnfinn- no need to apologize!! I hope my response didn't come across the wrong way.  You are absolutely correct, it was just out of sync with the thread of my recent comments, since they were specific to coefficient quantization, so wasn't sure if I misunderstood you.  What I see now if that you were probably just commenting on the question and may not have read through all the comments already posted.

Comment: In any event, I don't think we have completely gotten to the bottom of his problem yet, to his satisfaction- so other thoughts are welcome!!

Comment: @Dan Boschen: thanks, I am using the fft with extra zero padding to increase the resolution of the freq response.  I have also used freqz, and this works well for a single stage filter. However how would you suggest freqz be used with a 2 (or more) stage filter with inter-stage quantization?

Comment: I have a hunch why the sine-wave result gives more ideal behaviour than the impulse response result. A full scale impulse through the first stage that is quantized at the output can only pass coefficients represented by fewer bits than the output has. For example if I quantized the output to 16 bit but my smallest coefficient was a single lsb at 17 bit, then this value would output zero during an impulse response test. However during a sine-wave test this single lsb still has an opportunity to affect the overall result as full precision is kept until the final output - so an intuitive solution

Comment: Yes interesting question. I believe the quantization effect between the filter is independent of the filter frequency response. The inter-filter quanitzation is datpath quanitization, and does not change the frequency response of the filters which is driven by the coefficient quanitzation. Your frequency response should be determined from the convolution of the two filters. That said, the interstate quantization would increase the noise floor (and would be signal dependent on exact effect), but if we are careful to have enough precision throughout the datpath to exceed our filter rejection...

Comment: If we are careful that our datapath precision exceeds our dynamic range of interest, then the solution for the quantized coefficients using the DTFT will be an exact solution. In my answer I described two quantization scenarios: datapath and (briefly) coefficient quantization, the first impacts noise and the second inpacts the precise shape of the frequency response. The first effect is difficult to predict exactly so we use statistical approximations but the second effect is exact.

Comment: @John McGrath so in summary, to get the frequency response of the two filters I use coeff= conv(coeff_flt1, coeff,flt2), and then use freqz(coeff).  Quantization of the datapath does not effect the frequency response per se, except to the degree that it will impact the noise floor achieved (via quantization noise).   (Also I am not completely sure of your "impulse response test" that you describe as you need the actual quantized filter coeff, not what you measure at a quantized output, to compute the freq response.)  I am assuming that you know your filter coefficients?

Comment: @DanBoschen - Yes, the impulse response test uses the actual quantized filter coefficients. I already have these coefficients determined to meet my requirements. The filter response test was actually achieved by running a real impulse through the real fixed-point filter-chain, with all quantizations.

Comment: @DanBoschen - I guess the key takeaway here is simulating an impulse response in a quantized system and taking an FFT (with zero padding) of this gives the correct result only for a single filter. However, doing the same thing for a filter chain will not work. As you say, the quantization of the data path should only affect the SNR of the filter chain, which is what happens for 'normal' signals like sine waves.

Comment: Yes agreed, as a closed box verification test on a system an impulse test would not be accurate even for a single filter that is quantized at the output. (As the information about the coefficients with their higher precision would be lost. However you can predict what the response would be even with the cascaded system from the coefficient values if you know them a priori.

Comment: ...using the approach for example that the frequency response is determined using coeff= conv(coeff_filt1, coeff_filt2), freqz(coeff). While datapath quantization is set to meet your dynamic range requirement (approx 6dB/bit) as it would impact your quantization noise floor but not your linear system frequency response. (Quantization will create other spectral artifacts, which could be at frequencies you intended to attenuate, but I consider this a noise artifact, not part of the frequency response. Interesting problem @John McGrath, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41405/discussion-on-answer-by-john-mcgrath-inter-filter-bit-width).