# Do the digital filter coefficients need to be forced to sum to 1.0?

Tags: filters, digital

I coded a digital filer in Matlab based on equations I found for a Martin-Graham (low pass type).  It looks like it is working. So I want to smooth some data and then calculate the first derivative.  So time-tagged data comes in and the code computed the coefficients for those time points.  The data has some noise from quantization.  My questions are:
(1) Do the weights need to be “normalized” by forcing their sum to be 1.0?  I could just try some data but want to understand about normalizing.
(2) What do the negative coefficients mean?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When the coefficients of a FIR filter sum to one, the output of a constant input signal will be identical to the input. Basically, a constant signal is very smooth, therefore should be left untouched by a smoothing filter. Therefore, most low-pass filters are normalized to unit sum.

For the negative coefficients, I have nothing more than Dan's answer. when designing a filter to have certain properties, there will be a kind of balance in coefficients' values.

By the way, you can combine the smoothing and the derivative in one single filter. Generally, derivative-like filter coefficients sum to zero, as the derivative of a constant is... zero.

Answer (score 0):

No the digital filter coefficients need not be forced to sum to one, which normalizes the filter-- any scaling that is done is identical to adding a fixed gain to the data path. For floating point, where that gain is applied makes less of a difference but this will be a significant consideration for fixed point design.

This point is detailed further in [this other post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73341/what-is-the-correct-gain-of-an-rrc-filter/73364#73364), but a good rule of thumb for fixed point is to size the coefficients to have 2 bits more of precision than the data path. Then the coefficients themselves are scaled to maximize the range provided by the coefficient precision and the summation of the products is accumulated in an extended precision accumulator. The output of the filter can then be truncated back to the precision required on the datapath at the output of the filter (which may be more than that at the input depending on the system design at hand and purpose / application of the filter).

To understand the significance of negative valued coefficients, it may be helpful to realize that the filter coefficients for an FIR filter represent the impulse response of the filter (consider if you applied just a single "impulse" or unit sample at the input to an FIR filter, that the coefficients would emerge as the waveform at the filter output as we advance forward in time!).  Next understand that the Fourier Transform of the impulse response is the frequency response for the filter. So if we wanted an ideal low pass filter which is a rectangular function in frequency, we would need an impulse response as a Sinc function in time. The Sinc function has positive and negative values - wala!

It would need to be an infinitely long Sinc function in order to realize a perfect brickwall filter, so reality imposes us to truncate the filter, which is associated with the passband ripple, finite transition and stopband ripple of any realized low pass filter. Windowing the truncated impulse response helps reduce the passband and stopband ripple. This is a starting point in filter design. [This post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38620/what-is-the-suitable-design-method-to-the-filter/38621#38621) provides further details and considerations.